# Why doesn't a Lambda function that returns the result of tf.py_func/tf.numpy_function have an output shape, and how can I correct this behavior?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For example purposes, I've created two Python functions. One takes a value and just returns it; the other is a lambda function that returns a Tensor to evaluate the function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Lambda,Dense
def test_func(value):
  return value
test_func = np.vectorize(test_func)
test_op = lambda x: tf.numpy_function(test_func,[x],tf.float32)
input = Input(shape=(1,))
test_layer = Lambda(test_op)
model = Sequential()
model.add(input)
model.add(test_layer)
model.summary()
```

When I run this code on Tensorflow 1.14.x + Keras 2.2.x + Python 3.6.x, and even if I set the output_shape parameter of the Lambda layer, I get a Lambda layer with a "None" output shape:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lambda_1 (Lambda)            None                      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I test the code using a test tensor, I get the results I might expect:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    X = tf.constant([[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]])
    Y = tf.constant(2.0)
    X_out = test_op(X)
    Y_out = test_op(Y)
    print("X:",session.run(X))
    print("X shape: ",session.run(tf.shape(X_out)))
    print("Y:",session.run(Y_out))
    print("Y shape: ", session.run(tf.shape(Y_out)))
```

Output:

> X: [[1. 2.]  [3. 4.]]
>   X shape:  [2 2]
>   Y: 2.0
>   Y shape:  [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda)
>   **EDIT:**

For comparison purposes, I also created a neural network using the function found in [this page of documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda):

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Lambda
input = Input(shape=(1,))
def antirectifier(x):
    x -= K.mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    x = K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1)
    pos = K.relu(x)
    neg = K.relu(-x)
    return K.concatenate([pos, neg], axis=1)
lambda_ = Lambda(antirectifier)
lambda_ = Lambda(antirectifier)(input)
model = Model(inputs=[input],outputs=[lambda_])
model.summary()
```

As somewhat expected, this prints:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now - if I understand correctly - both tf.py_func and K.concatenate return a TensorFlow Tensor object. So, the question is, Why does all the code I posted here work, EXCEPT my tf.numpy_function layer?

Comment: I'll take a stab at why he downvoted (not me, but best guess): go ahead and read the help documents on [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just at a glance there has to be a *much* more concise way you can illustrate your problem with code, and going through the exercise may lead you to the answer on your own.

Comment: @Engineero: Noted. Hope my edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `np.vectorize`.

It says it uses numpy's broadcasting rules, and it might have something to do with that.

Check it out:

```
def test_func(value):
    return value

test_func = np.vectorize(test_func)
print(test_func(2))
print(test_func(2).shape)
```

Notice the result is `()`. So, Keras/Tensorflow is working fine as they are getting the output shape given by numpy. Numpy probably doesn't know what it's getting as an input (because it doesn't work with symbolic tensors).

Notice how it works normally if you pass an actual numpy array to the function:

```
print(test_func(np.array([2])))
print(test_func(np.array([2])).shape)

>>>> [2]
>>>> (1,)
```

But when Keras initializes a model, the actual numbers don't exist, and Numpy has no idea of what it will receive when you are "using" the model.

Comment: So, how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you really need numpy and vectorize? You can probably adapt your function.

Comment: In the worst case you can try to set `lambda_._keras_shape = (None, 1)`, but this is not recommended. I don't know if it works.

Comment: @DanielMöller: So, my code that doesn't work is supposed to represent code that is difficult, and may be impossible to adapt.

Comment: @DanielMöller: Also, I don't see that you have addressed my question of why Keras's documentation code (posted in my question) works, while my code doesn't - even though both my code and Keras's code both give the Lambda layers in their respective code a tensor.

Comment: The example is clearly not using numpy vectorize. The problem is definitely numpy vectorize. Try using `_keras_shape` to force the desired shape. You will not be able to make keras understand the shape of the numpy result when the result itself has no shape.